# How to screen mirror Android to non-smart TV?

Tags: hdmi, screen-mirroring

I bought a [USB C-HDMI cable](https://www.global-electronic.ro/cablu-hdmi-usb-tip-c-2m-kruger-matz_15453.html?id=112) to mirror my Samsung Galaxy M11 to my non-smart TV, but I get no signal. The TV has 3 HDMI ports and with every single one, I get no signal.

Is it a setting that I have to change on the phone or maybe on TV?

Comment: Most smartphones are not able to output HDMI in their USB-C port. Not sure about your phone.

Comment: Look at what this guy is saying:https://youtube.com/watch?v=HLE_Qcy3z50

Comment: That video is on a different phone so it is not relevant for you. If an Android phone has the capability to output HDMI over USB-c depends on the phone. Also there two types of cables, activate with an own converter and passive where the phone has the provide all the necessary signals.

Comment: Ok. I Understand.Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable you bought is an [MHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) cable using the [USB Type-C (MHL Alternate Mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link#USB_Type-C_(MHL_Alternate_Mode)).

For such a cable to work the phone needs to include special hardware. Additionally the TV has to support MHL, too as it's HDMI socket has to be MHL-enabled.

The MHL web site contains a [list of devices that support MHL](https://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1). There you can filter for Samsung devices.

In my opinion MHL is today an outdated technology originally developed for phone with Micro-USB socket. You can also see that on the list of supported devices. The last Samsung galaxy phone that supported MHL is the Galaxy S5 released in 2014. The last Samsung device with MHL support I recognize was released in 2015.

Comment: The Tv does not support MHL,maybe i will buy a Smart Tv in the future and i will mirror my phone wirelessly,idk .Anyway thanks for clarifications.